# Use a laravel service and inject the code into the Controller

Tags: php, laravel

how can I do a service and call that service in the controller without having so much code in the controller?
For example, to move this code to a service and to call it depending on what I ask for on the route
Controller code

```
public function convert(Request $request) {
        switch($request->query('source')) {
            case '1':
                $csv = Reader::createFromPath('');
                $csv = $csv->setOffset(1);
                $json = json_encode($csv, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                return response($json);
            break;
            case '2':
                $data = DB::table('users')->get();
                $json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                return response($json);
            break;
            default:
                $error = array(
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'Error'
                );
                return response()->json($error, 400);
        }
    }
```

So I have this code in the controller.
How can I write this code in a service and call that service when the route is 1 or 2?

I want to do a check in the controller of what I send on the route and take the data from a service depending on what I validate

Comment: what version of Laravel and PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Binding a service to your container is simple:

```
$this->app->singleton(MyServiceClass::class, function ($application) {
    return new MyServiceClass();
});
```

Now you may consume this service in your controller:

```
public function convert(MyServiceClass $myServiceClass, Request $request)
{
    return $myServiceClass->convert($request);
}
```

and of course `MyServiceClass` has the `convert` method as expected:

```
class MyServiceClass {
    public function convert(Request $request) {
        switch($request->query('source')) {
            case '1':
                $csv = Reader::createFromPath('');
                $csv = $csv->setOffset(1);
                $json = json_encode($csv, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                return response($json);
            break;
            case '2':
                $data = DB::table('users')->get();
                $json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                return response($json);
            break;
            default:
                $error = array(
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'Error'
                );
                return response()->json($error, 400);
        }
    }
}
```